# I'm getting a NullReferenceException (VB.Net) and don't see where it could be coming from (dev with 15+ years of experience perhaps having a 'moment')

Tags: vb.net, nullreferenceexception

None of the parameters are empty/null/nothing

```
auditAuthSuccess(UserName, olaHelper.batchID, olaHelper.authenticatedStudentIDSite)  '<-- I put a break on this line
```

Code execution halts there and I have no indications of an exception in my output window.

The signature for the auditAuthSuccess method is:

```
Public Shared Sub auditAuthSuccess(ByVal managementUserName As String, ByVal batchID As String, ByVal studentID As String)
        fooBar() '<-- I put a break here also and code halts as expected, but there's a NullReferenceException in the output window now
End Sub
```

When code is halted on the line calling fooBar(), the Call Stack shows:

> OLAWeb.DLL!Comptek.OLA.olaHelper.auditAuthSuccess(String managementUserName, String batchID, String studentID) Line 467 Basic

```
OLAWeb.DLL!Comptek.OLA.frmLogin.FinishLogin(System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs e, String UserName, String Password, String RedirectAddress, String strRoles) Line 234 + 0xc5 bytes Basic
```

No unmanaged code, no other methods, etc.. So were in the world is the NullReferenceException coming from?

http://pastebin.com/YDnVJBYf (code also here)

Comment: You could try breaking when a CLR exception is thrown: VS Debug -> Exceptions -> Check 'Thrown' from the same line as Common Language Runtime Exception.

Comment: I already had this enabled (and double-checked to be sure). The exception is thrown in my web-app assembly according to the Output window yet the debugger never actually halts for an exception.

Comment: Found it! The StudentID parameter was showing as "0" in my watch window, but it's actually retrieved passed as "olaHelper.studentID" and olaHelper is a helper class and studentID is a Public Shared ReadOnly property that refers to a session() variable that WAS Nothing, but the Get uses a Try...Catch block casting the session variable to an XElement, then using LINQ against that. The reference inside the try block was throwing the exception, but the whole point was to return 0 if a NRE was thrown (to provide a default value essentially). I didn't handle everything as I intended to though. :)

Comment: For what it's worth, my reputation is so low because I'm rarely here, because I seldom make silly mistakes like this (attempt to save face). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can try to switch on the Visual Studio runtime exception info:
Visual Studio > Debug > Exeptions > Common Language Runtime Exceptions > Thrown = YES.
[image: Visual Studio Runtime Exceptions]

Regards